# Why is Random.nextInt() and Math.random going out of the range I set?

Tags: java, random

So I needed to get random numbers between 25 and 75 and I tried two things:

```
System.out.println(random.nextInt(75)+25);
System.out.println((int)(Math.random()*75) + 25);
```

From what I understood, the "75" I wrote in both lines should be the greatest number I get and the "25" should be the smallest number. However, I got numbers like:

```
84,94,82,79,98 // these are only the numbers that went out of range
```

I guess I misunderstood the rules of nextInt and Math.random. How can I get the numbers I want(between 25 and 75)?

Comment: 75+25>75, use nextint(50)

Comment: `random.nextInt(75)` represents range of values `[0, 75)` (75 is exclusive). When you add 25 minimal value becomes 0+25=25 and maximal value 75+25=100 which gives range `[25, 100)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about this part:

```
random.nextInt(75) + 25
```

You're generating a number between 0 and 74, then adding 25. This generates a random number from 25 to 99. If it generates 74 and you add 25, it becomes 99.

You need to subtract the lower bound before generating:

```
random.nextInt(75 - 25) + 25)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But then I tried with smaller numbers `System.out.println(random.nextInt(1)+1);` and I got only the number "1" everytime. Shouldn't I be getting "2" as well?

Comment: @Alexis676 Me and the other answer actually got a small detail wrong. The second number is actually exclusive. You need to add one to the upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

The range of your examples is `25` to `100` because you add twenty-five to the result. You wanted something like

```
System.out.println(random.nextInt(75 - 25) + 25);
```

because you want a value in the range `0` to `50` and then you shift that up twenty-five by adding twenty-five.

Comment: Max value returned from `random.nextInt(75)` is 74 final range is up to 99 *inclusive*, or 100 *exclusive*.